# Azure topic and sending message over MQTT

Tags: azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub, azure-servicebus-topics

Is it possible to send messages to azure to any custom topic via mqtt. All example that I've found so far work with standard topics

```
'devices/' + hubName + '/messages/events/'
'devices/' + hubName + '/messages/devicebound/#'
```

Btw, I tried to send/subscribe on the topic/subscription above with MQTT.fx application and never received messages, although the connection was successful.

Comment: What did you mean about 'never received messages'? Did it mean that the back end can not receive the messages which sent from MQTT.fx(Device-To-Cloud), or MQTT.fx can not receive the messages which sent from service(Cloud-To-Device)?

Comment: MQTT.fx being subscribed on devices/mydevice/messages/devicebound/#, never received messages sent from MQTT.fx to devices/mydevice/messages/events/ (I use the application as sender and receiver). Connection is established (green light turned on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The topic filter of `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#` is to subscribe receiving message from IoT Hub(Cloud-To-Device message), it think you need to understand the difference about device-to-cloud message and cloud-to-device message from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-devguide-messaging).
The topic of `devices/{device_id}/messages/events/` is for sending a device-to-cloud message from device.

You can use [Device Explorer](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-csharp/tree/master/tools/DeviceExplorer) to test this issue. When you send a message to device with the tool, MQTT.fx will receive the message.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for clarification on MQTT.fx. Yesterday I was able to send messages to devices/{device_id}/messages/events/ from Python source code (using paho.mqtt). As a reference I used code from https://github.com/gloveboxes/Azure-IoT-Hub-with-Python-and-MQTT/blob/master/weather_mqtt/weather_mqtt.py. Now I need to publish to custom topic. I've created endpoint, assigned to topic, and route for the endpoint. But I'm not able to publish. Which url should I use? Thanks!

Comment: @amplifier, IoT Hub is not a general-purpose pub-sub messaging broker, it only supports the documented topic names and topic filters, but not supports custom topic. More information please see this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support).

Comment: Finally I did it use routing. Take a look here please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160000/azure-iothub-devicemessage-and-route-filter

Comment: @amplifier, i have looked the thread you mentioned. In this thread the topicName is not a custom topic filter for IoT Hub, `$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8` is just parameter. I am confused about what is the relation with `custom topic` and route message to an endpoint in above comment?

Comment: @amplifier, in addition to above comment. To some extent, you can refer to the the topic name with device id as a custom topic. But in fact, it is different with the custom topic for mqtt broker.

Comment: yes, I put a special parameter into the message, then I set up endpoints (Home->IoT hub->Endpoints) and routes (Home->IoT hub->Routes)  and a query string for each of the routes, and now my messages eventually go into a particular topic according to the special parameter

Comment: how can I refer to the topic name with device id as c custom topic?

Comment: You can refer to `'devices/{device_id}/messages/events/'` as a topic name(for you it is custom topic) for publish the message to IoT Hub, and `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#` as a topic for subscribing message sent from cloud. But i don't think this concept is related to routing to endpoint,or in another word, the route config is not related with this question.

Comment: Michael I don't c2d messages at the moment. And let me clarify my terminology. Under custom topic I understand a topic that create on azure portal. But 'devices/{device_id}/messages/events/' as built-in topic

Comment: In MQTT.fx app, it can not receive the d2c message via subscribing the topic `devices/{device_id}/messages/devicebound/#`.