# Azure IoTHub DeviceMessage and route filter

Tags: python, azure, mqtt, azure-iot-hub

I use *python* and *paho.mqtt* for sending messages to cloud
I set up endpoint and route. When I set query string to *true*, everything works fine

```
messageDict = {}
systemPropertiesDict = {"contentType": "application/json", "contentEncoding": "utf-8", "iothub-message-source": "deviceMessages", "iothub-enqueuedtime": "2017-05-08T18:55:31.8514657Z"}
messageDict = {"systemProperties": systemPropertiesDict}
messageDict["appProperties"] = {}
body = '{id:1}'
messageDict["body"] = body
root = {"message":messageDict}
msg = json.dumps(root, indent=2).encode('utf-8')
print("Message to send", msg)
self.client.publish(topicName, msg)
```

But if I set the query string to *$body.id = 1*, then I don't receive any messages.

Any ideas, guys?

Comment: Hi amplifier, you can try the answer's solution to see if it works. It works for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The route not working because the content encoding type is not set. All the "systemProperties" in your code actually as message body not system properties. Content encoding type set by this method doesn't take effect.

Add "$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8" to the topic. Then it will look like this:

```
devices/{yourDeviceId}/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

But to make the route query works on your message you need use this query string: $body.message.body.id = 1

Two edits to make:

First, change `body = '{id:1}'` to `body = {"id":1}` to make the id as a string.

Second, change `topicName` value to this one:

`devices/{yourDeviceId}/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8`

If possible, it is suggesting to use [Azure IoT SDK for Python](https://github.com/Azure/azure-iot-sdk-python) to communicate with Azure IoT Hub.

Comment: Hi! So you mean that I need to remove systemPropertiesDict and leave only body part (along with adding $.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8 to the query of course)?

Comment: @amplifier I update my answer with two edits you need make. You can check and have a try. As for systemProperties in your code, you can remove them if you don't need. Feel free let me know if it doesn't work.

Comment: @Rite Han you're awesome! It works!
 body = '{id:1, "text":"hello!!!"}'
 print("Message to send", body)
 self.client.publish(topicName, body)

btw, I don't need quotes for id (it works anyway)

Comment: @Rite Han Azure SDK is great but current requirement is mqtt-only way. Where did you find docs on *$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8*?

Comment: @amplifier I didn't find this on document. You can open an issue to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/iot-hub/iot-hub-mqtt-support). This is what Roman Kiss found. Please check [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/azure/en-US/dafff4bb-7c59-4ab1-96ed-9f3834488f12/azure-iothub-devicemessage-and-route-filter?forum=azureiothub).

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third-party library (like paho-mqtt) you have to specify the content type and the encoding of the message.
IoT Hub route messages with content type "application/json" and content encoding: "utf-8" or "utf-16" or "utf-32".
Using MQTT protocol you can set this info with $.ct and $.ce.

topic example:

`devices/{MY_DEVICE_ID}/messages/events/%24.ct=application%2fjson&%24.ce=utf-8`

URL encoding of

`devices/{MY_DEVICE_ID}/messages/events/$.ct=application/json&$.ce=utf-8`

Here you could found more info:
https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/iot-hub-message-routing-now-with-routing-on-message-body/