# No ContentType system property on messages sent to IoT hub via MQTT

Tags: azure-iot-hub

I want to use IoT hub message routing; according to [this azure blog](https://azure.microsoft.com/it-it/blog/iot-hub-message-routing-now-with-routing-on-message-body/), I have to set the message's ContentType and ContentEncoding to application/json and a supported encoding. I am sending module messages through MQTT and [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51160000/azure-iothub-devicemessage-and-route-filter) says I should use a $.ct=application/json&$.ce=utf-8 url suffix.

I would expect telemetry message `{'signalStrength': -19.0}` sent to topic    `devices/E660CCC14B482231/modules/MyModule/messages/events/%24.ct=application%2Fjson&%24.ce=utf-8` to result in an IoT hub message with systemProperties 'content-encoding' and 'content-type' set, yet IoT explorer shows me that neither system properties are set:

```
{
  "body": {
    "signalStrength": -19
  },
  "enqueuedTime": "Thu Nov 10 2022 13:51:59 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)",
  "properties": {
    "serialNumber": "E660CCC14B482231"
  },
  "systemProperties": {
    "iothub-connection-device-id": "E660CCC14B482231",
    "iothub-connection-module-id": "MyModule",
    "iothub-connection-auth-method": "{'scope':'module','type':'sas','issuer':'iothub'}",
    "iothub-connection-auth-generation-id": "638006753232047843",
    "iothub-enqueuedtime": 1668113519787,
    "iothub-message-source": "Telemetry",
    "dt-dataschema": "dtmi:MyModule:MyDevice;1",
    "x-opt-sequence-number": 1192144,
    "x-opt-offset": "274899831448",
    "x-opt-enqueued-time": 1668113519865
  }
}
```

I've tried content types of "application/JSON" and "application/json", tried url-escaping "$.ct" and "$.ce", but I never see content-type and content-encoding show up in the systemProperties.

Comment: add to the topic: **$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8** and don't use an escaping.

Comment: @RomanKiss: I have tried that, same result.

Comment: it looks like, the Azure IoT Explorer didn't show output correctly. For test purpose, route the telemetry data in the IoT Hub to the storage and check the messages there. If the content-type or content-encoding is not correct (such as application/json and utf-8), the message body is Base64 encoded.

Comment: @RomanKiss: you are right, IoT Explorer never shows content-type and content-encoding systemProperties, even when they are present. Routing based on message body works now, with topic suffix $.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sending telemetry to

```
devices/E660CCC14B482231/modules/MyModule/messages/events/$.ct=application%2Fjson&$.ce=utf-8
```

does set ContentType and ContentEncoding, but IoT explorer won't show them as system properties.